# With client credential flow, access token getting generated without delegate access from any app within same tenant

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-authentication

I am setting a background process which will communicate with API secured by Azure AD. Without giving delegate access to API, Client App is able to generate access token

Using client credential flow, Is it possible to generate access token for web api without giving delegate permission. I am able to generate it but according to it should not happen. Any app created in my tenant is able to generate the token for web api without delegate permission.

I have followed below sample on github. 
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-daemon

It should not be able to generate access token, if no delegate access is provided.

Comment: Either I give delegate access or not, content of token is same. If i give application permission then only it is coming in token. How to validate on API side if delegate permission is provided or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal. If you are using client credential flow, even if your client app not have the application permission and delegated permission, it will be able to generate the access token. But you could not use this token to call the api, because the token does not have the permissions in its claim. You could decode the token in https://jwt.io/ , then you can see the permissions as below.

[image]

**Update**:

If you want to check the delegated permissions, you need to use [ropc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc) flow. Check the `scope` in the response, they are the delegated permissions.

[image]

Comment: Yes, it is the API developer's responsibility to check the caller has the necessary permissions for the current operation.

Comment: Generated token is same, either I give delegate permission or not. How to validate on API side to check if delegate permission is provided or not.

Comment: @mohitgarg The token generated by the client credential flow just appears the application permission, to check the delegated permission you need to use [ROPC flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc). It seems you cannot check if delegate permission is provided or not on API side. But you can check it in the client app side, navigate to the azure ad in the portal -> App Registrations(Preview) -> API permissions, then you can check if the permission has been granted.

Comment: @mohitgarg To use ropc flow, you could see my update.

Comment: Yup with ROPC flow I am not able to generate access token without delegate permission which is correct. But ours is background service which need to communicate with API secured by Azure AD.

Comment: @mohitgarg Actually, I think I have answered your question `With client credential flow, access token getting generated without delegate access from any app within same tenant` , could you accept it as the answer? For other further questions not related to this topic, I recommend you to ask them in another question.